# how to remove header links class with ul tag in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, header

I'm on Magento 2.1.6. The header links are rendered with this structure:

```
<ul class="header links">
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  ...
</ul>
```

My HTML structure is like this:

[image]

How can I remove **`ul`** tag?? I do not require **`ul`** tag.

Answer (score 4):

You can change Links.php at this location :- vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Html

Probably on line no 76 remove the UL or change it to DIV

Comment: i did not find in ul tag,here not available ul tag

Comment: check in the end of file ,  "     protected function _toHtml()
    {
        if (false != $this->getTemplate()) {
            return parent::_toHtml();
        }

        $html = '';
        if ($this->getLinks()) {
            $html = '<ul . ($this->hasCssClass() ? ' class="' . $this->escapeHtml(
                $this->getCssClass()
            ) . '"' : '') . '>';
            foreach ($this->getLinks() as $link) {
                $html .= $this->renderLink($link);
            }
            $html .= '</ul>';
        }

        return $html;
    }
} "     or search getLinks

Comment: it is working sorry i am open Link.php file

Comment: can i overite this file??how??

Comment: Great ! I hope you got what you were looking for

Answer (score 2):

I am extending the answer given by Manoj..

It is required to create a custom module, let us say Stack_Links, follow this link for the same [Dev Doc](https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/)

Then create di.xml file within \app\code\Stack\Links\etc directory of module as below:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">     
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" type="Stack\Links\Block\Links" />
</config>
```

Then Copy

> \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Links.php

file to

> \app\code\Stack\Links\Block\Links.php

Then modify _toHtml() method according to requirement such as below to remove UL tag.

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    if (false != $this->getTemplate()) {
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }

    $html = '';
    if ($this->getLinks()) {            
        foreach ($this->getLinks() as $link) {
            $html .= $this->renderLink($link);
        }            
    }

    return $html;
}
```